# Why does `flask_bootstrap` fail to import?

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

When running a flask app, Apache2's `error.log` shows that the `flask_bootstrap` module cannot be found:

```
[wsgi:warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
[wsgi:warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[mpm_event:notice] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[core:notice] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=18587): Target WSGI script '/var/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[wsgi:error] mod_wsgi (pid=18587): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi'.
[wsgi:error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[wsgi:error]     from myapp import app as application 
[wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/myapp/myapp/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
[wsgi:error]     from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
[wsgi:error] ImportError: No module named flask_bootstrap
```

I have configured the `venv` as per `myapp.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName yourdomain.com
ServerAdmin youemail@email.com

WSGIProcessGroup myapp
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-home=/var/www/myapp/myapp/venv

<Directory /var/www/myapp/myapp/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The module is available both system wide and in the venv:

```
root@host:/var/www/myapp# python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
>>> Bootstrap
<class 'flask_bootstrap.Bootstrap'>
```

And...

```
root@host:/var/www/myapp# source myapp/venv/bin/activate
(venv) root@host:/var/www/myapp# python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
>>> Bootstrap
<class 'flask_bootstrap.Bootstrap'>
```

I note that there is a warning about the 2.7.11 vs 2.7.12 mismatch, but is the minor version really the issue?

**Edit 1**

As per [the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/), added the following to `myapp.wsgi`

```
activate_this = '/var/www/myapp/myapp/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Didn't make any difference.

Comment: The patch level version difference doesn't matter. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html#python-patch-level-mismatch

Comment: Since you are testing imports as ``root``, I would be concerned over whether installed package has correct permissions and can be found by user that Apache runs as. Also, what do you get for ``sys.prefix`` from Python interpreter for activated virtual environment? That should match what you give to ``python-home`` option.

Comment: Yep, `sys.prefix` indeed matches `python-home` :/

Comment: Did a `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` - didn't make any difference :/

Comment: Using ``activate_this`` is not the recommended way. How to use virtual environment with mod_wsgi is described in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: BTW, not that it will make a difference, although it highlights some issue with security elsewhere in Apache configuration, the path to ``Directory`` should be ``/var/www/myapp``.

Comment: I would also suggest setting ``LogLevel`` to ``info`` so mod_wsgi logs more about what it is doing. The log messages it outputs when loading the WSGI script the first time may help to verify whether actually being loaded in daemon mode correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after Graham persuading me that my "fix" (moving the two lines into the `<Directory>` directive) was not really the fix and probably a sign something else was wrong, I decided to dig deeper.

Following the docs, specifically [confirming the location of the virtual environment](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html#location-of-the-virtual-environment), I was surprised to discover that when activating the virtual environment on my local box (not via the wsgi app):

```
sys.prefix = '/usr'
```

when I expected it to be:

```
sys.prefix = '/var/www/myapp/myapp/venv'
```

I have no idea how this occurred. Maybe a result of doing all the initial work as `root`.

However, pleased to say that deleting and remaking the virtual environment, this time as a normal user, everything seems good.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This Answer, after being posted, was discovered by @Bridgey to be wrong.  See his other Answer.

---

It turns out that the problem was that the two lines:

```
WSGIProcessGroup myapp
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

should have been inside the `<Directory>`!

So, the `myapp.conf` now looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName yourdomain.com

        WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-home=/var/www/myapp/myapp/venv
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi

        <Directory /var/www/myapp/myapp>
                WSGIProcessGroup myapp
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In fairness, this is as per the example in [the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/#configuring-apache).

Big thanks to all those who commented :)

Comment: That can't be the reason, they would have worked where they were. By moving them inside they are now actually ignored because you have the wrong directory path as argument to ``Directory``. Use the check in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#embedded-or-daemon-mode and you likely will now find that your WSGI application isn't actually running in daemon mode anymore.

Comment: Hey Graham, why do you think the directory path is wrong? The python script for the app really is in `/var/www/myapp/myapp` - yes, 2 x `myapp`. Thanks!

Comment: The path to the WSGI script in ``WSGIScriptAlias`` is ``/var/www/myapp/myapp.wsgi``. That means the directory is ``/var/www/myapp``. The ``myapp.wsgi`` is the filename component. You appear to be pointing it at a file different to the Django ``wsgi.py`` file which would be in ``/var/www/myapp/myapp``. IOW, it is the path in ``WSGIScriptAlias`` which is important, not where the Django ``wsgi.py`` file is.

Comment: Hey Graham, this isn't Django - this is an entirely bespoke Flask app. `myapp.wsgi` knows to import from the `myapp` sub-directory. Looking at the docs, I don't see anything that says the `<Directory>` directive must point to the same directory containing the `.wsgi` file. Thanks!

Comment: See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html#the-wsgiscriptalias-directive Ignore comments about Django, same issue still applies. The scoping by using ``Directory`` applies to directives like ``WSGIProcessGroup`` as well. This is a fundamental part of how Apache works. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory

Comment: FWIW, I see so many people getting this wrong, for ``Require all granted`` and ``Order/Allow``, yet still works, that almost looks like Ubuntu has broken the default ASF access control philosophy whereby access to everything should be disallowed by default.